# Extensions obtained adding torsion points of an elliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, galois-theory, galois-groups

When adding to the rational the $p$-torsion points $E[p]$ of an elliptic curve we obtain an extension containing the $p$-th roots of the unity, and whose Galois group can be embedded in $GL(2, \mathbb{F}_p)$. To what extent are such extensions coming from elliptic curves?

I mean, assume $K/\mathbb{Q}$ to be an extension whose Galois group can be embedded in $GL(2, \mathbb{F}_p)$ and containing the $p$-th roots of the unity (which is required to expect a positive answer), is $K$ obtained adding to $\mathbb{Q}$ the torsion points of some elliptic curve defined over the rationals?

Note that I'm not considering a particular Galois representation, but just Galois groups that can be embedded in some way into $GL(2, \mathbb{F}_p)$. Thanks!

Comment: In general there will be further conditions on the possible subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$. First as you mention the determinant must be surjective onto $\mathbf{F}_p^{\times}$. It is also expected that for non CM ell. curves over Q and p big enough (independent of the curve), the Galois representation will be surjective onto $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$. A good starting point for this is Serre's article *Propriétés des points d'ordre fini des courbes elliptiques*, Inventiones 1972.

Comment: But if you fix a subgroup $G \subset \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$ which occurs as the image of Galois for some ell. curve, then I think this is good question to determine which Galois extensions $K/\mathbf{Q}$ having Galois group $G$ can occur.

Comment: I expect some additional condition to be required as well. However just considering the group and not the representation i also expect some general positive result.

Comment: Once you fix an embedding into the general linear group, Serre's conjecture, now a theorem, implies that the representation arises from a modular form. Deligne's theory and the theory of congruences between modular forms shows that such representations indeed come from two dimensional torsion subgroups of the jacobians of the modular curves, but I think these don't have to come from an elliptic curve.

Comment: @Maurizio : an example of positive result is the following. Take the elliptic curve $E: y^2+y=x^3-x$ which has conductor $37$. Then for any prime number $p$ the Galois representation $\rho_{E,p} : \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}/\mathbf{Q}) \to \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$ is surjective. Moreover, if you believe the conjecture I mentioned in my first comment, then the question for subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$ only arises for a finite number of $p$ (leaving aside the CM case).

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Taylor proved that for $p=5$, the icosahedral ones are obtained from the 5-torsion of elliptic curves (but you might need to enlarge the base field), see http://www.math.harvard.edu/~rtaylor/artin2.pdf. This implies a negative answer to your question, because you need to enlarge the base field (the curves are not necessary defined over $\mathbb{Q}$), but for this group and $p=5$ the answer is almost yes. Also you need some restrictions in the groups you consider, since the diagonal diagonal subgroup (which is abelian) is not obtained in this way.

Comment: The $p=5$ case is misleading. The associated modular curve has genus 0 so if there are no local obstructions to there being points, then there are points. A more illuminating example would be $p$ some random 10-digit prime. The moduli space of elliptic curves giving rise to this Galois representation would be a curve of huge genus and there's no reason at all that it should have any rational points, so in general I don't think it's reasonable to expect that a Galois representation, even with cyclo det, should be the $p$-torsion of an ell curve.

Comment: Here's another cheap source of counterexamples: consider a reducible 2-dimensional Galois representation with cyclotomic determinant and a 1-dimensional subspace where Galois acts trivially. By Mazur this won't come from an ell curve if $p\geq 11$.

Comment: Thanks everybody for their comments.
@Kevin: why is this a counterexample? The question is about the group, that is not the representation itself but just the image, up to isomorphism.

Comment: @Maurizio : Mazur's celebrated theorem tells us that (in the non CM case) for $p$ big enough, the image of Galois cannot be contained in a Borel subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$. The bound on $p$ is uniform on $E$ and actually quite low (I think $p>37$ will do). See *Modular curves and the Eisenstein ideal*, Publ. Math. IHES 1977.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question is discussed very carefully in Section 3 of the paper *Mod $p$ representations
on elliptic curves*, by Frank Calegari (available [here](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~fcale)).

In particular, after noting that the answer is positive when $p \leq 5$ (as was already
observed in the comments above), he proves (in Theorems 3.3 and 3.4) that if 
$p \geq 7$ then there exists a continuous representation $\rho: Gal(\overline{\mathbb Q}/
\mathbb Q) \to GL_2(\mathbb F_p)$ with cyclotomic determinant which *does not* come from
the $p$-torsion of an elliptic curve.  (He also notes that the same result was established
by Dieulefait, in the paper *Existence of non-elliptic mod $\ell$ Galois representations for every  $\ell > 5$*.)

Comment: Nice answer, i look forward to give a careful look at that paper soon. Thanks!